Run JUnit tests from multiple projects at once
I have a repository of projects, each containing JUnit tests. I am looking for either a method or a framework to run them all at once, instead of manually running for each project.
After some research I found that RogerRabbit from codeproject offers more or less the exact functinoality that I need, but it seems like it was deprecated since the dependency won't resolve no matter what I try (I am using maven and IntelliJ 2023 community edition with JDK17).
I am aware of some similar questions on SO regarding this, but all that I found were asked ~10 years ago, so I am hoping for more up-to-date information. Thanks in advance.

What about creating a "wrapper" project containing all of these projects, and then running its tests?

Can you please describe more detail what: I have a repository of projects,  this means? A single repository contains several projects?

@khmarbaise I have a folder containing 5 project folders, each containing an arbitrary number of folders that contain .java files and their respective tests

Are those folders independant projects or are they related ... Spring Boot like or JEE like ? please give more information otherwise it is impossible to even guess..

@khmarbaise as far as structure they are unrelated, independent generic projects, each containing a class definition .java file and its corresponding tests class

That means my suggestion is to create aggregator pom file and from that you can run all of them into one go.

Thanks for all the suggestions. In the end the simplest thing to do was run mvn test in each project subdirectory through a bash script, which is not perfect but it works.

You can create a project and add them as modules or you can make use of git submodules. I've used gitsumodules and I am happy with it. It has its own cost though.
